# mysql partial restore from backup

Tags: sql, mysql, backup

Due to a server crash I need to restore some rows, created within a certain period of time, from the backup (located on my local machine) onto the live db on server.

To select the rows in question I plan to do something like this from the backupdatabase:

```
SELECT *
FROM access AS t1
WHERE AccessId IN (
SELECT AccessId FROM access_completed AS t1
WHERE (TIMEDIFF(CCompleteDateTime, "2011-01-24 02:00:00") < 23 AND TIMEDIFF(CCompleteDateTime, "2011-01-24 02:00:00") > 0)
)
```

How do I insert the resulting rows into the live db?

Comment: Do you want to do it in the same query at the same time? if yes, then is better you create a procedure to do the job, perheps one trigger to start at the wished time..  what exctly y want to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) on the backup and [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) to load data.

`INTO OUTFILE` dumps the selected data to a local file, in a format that MySQL can parse back using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. So you just have to dump and load like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [rest of your query] INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/outfile'
```

Copy outfile to the other server

And on the other server:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE /tmp/outfile' INTO TABLE access;
```

---

It would also work with [`FEDERATED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html) tables. This would allow to query the backup database from the main server; so you could do `INSERT INTO access ... SELECT ... FROM federated_access ...`.

Comment: brilliant - you just saved my evening